Mandelstam variables
For a while now I have been struggling with a problem I am facing when considering the 2 to 2 process (Mandestam variables), and I would like to have an understanding of what is going on.
Considering a 2 to 2 process: $A(p_a)+B(p_b)\rightarrow C(p_c)+D(p_d)$
I want to understand how constraints (which are these constraints?) affect the independency of the Lorentz invariant quantities.
Now things get mixed up all the time. In some sources we pay attention to the components of the four vectors, in some not. And I want to understand what is going on here? On-shell, off-shell and what else.
So, the number of lorentz invariant quantities is 10: 4 on-shell conditions + 6 $p_ip_j$ scalar product of four vectors.
These are two comments in two different sources, which I will link:
1: https://web2.ph.utexas.edu/~vadim/Classes/2022f/STU.pdf

"The 4-momenta of the 2 incoming and 2 outgoing particles satisfy 8 constraints: the on-shell conditions for each particle and the net 4-momentum conservation.
Altogether, this gives us 4 × 4 − 8 = 8 independent momentum variables, and the number of independent Lorentz-invariant combinations of these variables is only 8 − 6 = 2."

2: https://edu.itp.phys.ethz.ch/hs10/ppp1/PPP1_2.pdf (page 3)

"Once again, the constraints are: $p_i^2=m_i^2$(i=1,2,3,4) and $p_1+p_2=p_3+p_4$
If m1 = m3 and m2 =m4, elastic scattering takes place. Consider the Lorentz invariant, 4 on-shell conditions + 6 $p_ip_j$ scalar product of four vectors from which 4 are linearly dependent and 2 are not. Four of them have to be linearly dependent, since there are only two degrees of freedom in the system (center of mass energy and scattering angle)."

So there are several things that I don't understand.
One can show that in addition to the particle masses, the  so-called Mandelstam variables are sufficient to describe the kinematics of the scattering process. What is meant with  kinematics? And how one shows that?
Constrain? I don't understand the use of this word here.
independent lorentz invariant quantity? Independent in what way?
Where does this come from: "4 × 4 − 8 = 8"?
I don't understand how constrains reduce the number of independent (whatever that means) lorentz invariant quantities?
And additionally, one can notice that in case 1) we have 16 Lorentz independent quantities, while in 2)  there are 10 LI quantities

$s$ and $t$ are independent.

I always thought that the number of invariants in $4n-10$ for $n\geq 4$ particle scattering? The $-10$ is due to the degrees of freedom from the Poincare group (for $n<4$, $n(n-1)/2$). Then, the number of variables for $n=4$ is $6$, but the number of constraints is $1$ namely $s + t + u = \sum_{i=1}^4 m_i^2$. For example, in $n = 5$ scattering, there are then $10$ variables and $5$ constraints. I could be wrong though which is why I commented for clarity.

@MathZilla this argument is clearly wrong, consider scattering 4 particles in dimensions higher than four, the dof count according to your calculation is then possibly negative when the space time dimension is high. The independent variables are always counted by invariant building blocks you could construct, in the case of 2-2 it’s always 2, s and t, other terms are just constant.

@Mmmao sorry for not giving a more general formula. The general number of invariants for $d$-dimensions is $dn-L$ where $d$ is the number of spacetime dimensions, $n$ is the usual number of particle scattering, and $L$ is the dimension of the Poincare group. The $4$ is $4n-10$ comes from the dimension of the momenta.

The question is really what the four-point amplitude is a function of (these variables specify the kinematic configuration for the scattering). It must surely depend just on the $p_i\cdot p_j$ by Lorentz symmetry. There are 10 such quantities and they are constrained by $8$ equations, namely $p_i^2 = -m_i^2$ (that's four equations) together with $p_1+p_2+p_3+p_4=0$ (that's more four equations since each $p_i$ has four components). So there are two independent variables, which are often conveniently taken to be $s$ and $t$.

@MathZilla Again, the formula you have is wrong, consider four point scattering, 10 space-time dimensions, the number of Lorentz generators is then 45, by your formula the number of independent variables is -5 which is clearly wrong.


we have 16 Lorentz independent quantities

This is not was is being said, it says independent momentum variables. The components of 4-momentum are not Lorentz-invariants, so these two concepts are distinct, despite related.

while in 2) there are 10 LI quantities

Again, that is not what is being said. In case two we are counting how many independent constraints we have.

Let's clarify some definitions:

Lorentz invariant: For 4-vectors, what is Lorentz invariant is its scalar product. If we have $a_\mu$ and $b_\mu$, the quantity $a_\mu b^\mu$ is Lorentz invariant.
Constraint: It is a functional relation that should be satisfied by your variables. For example, it is easy to solve $x+y=0$, but if we add the constraints $x>0$ and $y> 0$, this equation has no solution.
** Independent constraint:** Sometimes, the constraints of the problem are redundant. For example, if I say $x>0$ and $x>2$, both relations are constraining the value of $x$, but they are redundant, since to satisfy the first automatically guarantee to satisfy the second.
Independent variables: it is the number of variables that could be considered unconstrained, i.e., the number of degrees of freedom. For example, a particle in a plane is subjected to the constrain $z=0$. Since $x,y$ can vary freely, they are the independent variables and the degree of freedom is 2.



I don't understand how constrains reduce the number of independent (whatever that means) lorentz invariant quantities?

Each constraint will stablish a relation that should be satisfied by the variables of the problem. We could always reduce the number of variables to satisfy it identically.
Example: in the problem where $x+y=0$, both variables could not be considered independent. But if we define a independent variable $\alpha$ such that $x=\alpha$ and $y=-\alpha$, the constraint is always satisfied.


Where does this come from: "4 × 4 − 8 = 8"?

In the problem you are studying, there are 16 variables, 4 components of 4 $p_\mu$. However, there are 8 independent constraints. The number of independent constraints is well explained in case 2, where it explicitly enumerates the total 12 constraints, but says that 4 of them are dependent, resting 8 Independent constraints. Each constraint eliminates one degree of freedom, so of the initial 16 variables, we end with 8 independent variables. The Lorentz Independent combination of these variables are scalar products of the form above.
Note: the word Independent in Lorentz Independent means it does not vary under Lorentz transformations, it does not comes by the concept "Independent" in terms of constraints
